# SQL connection error occasionally

Tags: 7, comments

I am using v7.14 and with comment module, it's observed that following SQL error appeared occasionally when posting a comment, any idea about the root cause of the issue ?

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later. 
Error messagePDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '70-2-content_access_rid' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node_access} (nid, realm, gid, grant_view, grant_update, grant_delete) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5), (:db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 70 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => content_access_rid [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 2 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 70 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => taxonomy_access_role [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 5 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 0 ) in node_access_write_grants() (line 3417 of D:\wordpress\drupal\modules\node\node.module)...